# enable preview features for gretty plugin

Tags: java, spring-mvc, tomcat, gradle, gretty

I'm trying to run Spring MVC app using gretty plugin for Gradle (JVM version is 14)
To deploy app I use `tomcatRun` task (tomcat version is 8.5.49).

If i use some preview feature (e.g. `java.lang.String#formatted method`) I have to add `enable-preview` flag to `compileJava` task:

```
compileJava {
    options.compilerArgs += '--enable-preview'
}
```

However, if `build.gradle` contains such changes, something goes wrong and the following message appears in logs:

`INFO: No Spring WebApplicationInitializer types detected on classpath`
As a result all app endpoints aren't available.

In case of using `jettyRun` task the following exception is thrown:

```
17:14:38 WARN  Failed startup of context o.a.g.JettyWebAppContext@2715644a
java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: Preview features are not enabled for com/config/ApplicationDispatcherServletInitializer (class file version 58.65535). Try running with '--enable-preview'
```

Is it possible to use preview features with gretty plugin?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by adding `--enable-preview` to the list of JVM arguments in gretty configuration:

**`build.gradle`**

```
gretty {
    jvmArgs = ['--enable-preview']
}
```

Checked on both Jetty(9.4.24.v20191120) and Tomcat(8.5.49)